# In what noninformative priors turn out to be informative?

Tags: prior, jeffreys-prior

When searching about noninformative priors on internet, one can read here and there that those priors in fact turn out to be informative. However, I did not yet read a real argument about that.

So my question: in what noninformative (typically Jeffreys') priors turn out to be informative ?

Comment: Check the thread I marked as a duplicate of yours. It has a good discussion of this topic. TL;DR there is no such a thing as "uninformative" prior, priors always carry some sort of information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was aware of that discussion. May I ask here: you say

"there is no such a thing as "uninformative" prior, priors always carry some sort of information"

But how do you define what does "carry information" mean for a prior ? Because without explanation that seems a bit dogmatic to me (and it was precisely the topic of my question)

Maybe I can open a new discussion with this question ?

Comment: this is answered in the linked thread. But simple answer:  uninformative prior should not influence the result and that is not the case, since the choice of prior always has some effect on the result.